# How to Remove NULL (00) from Machine Code?

Tags: assembly, shellcode

I need to know how i remove the null (00) from machine code. i wrote the code in Assembly Language. It running Successfully. I need the output without NULL

```
.data
  Bash:
      .asciz "/bin/hostname"
  Null1:
      .int 0
  AddrToBash:
      .int 0
  NULL2:
      .int 0

  .text
      .globl _start

_start:
       #execute routine

       xor  %eax,%eax
       movl $Bash, AddrToBash
       movl $11,%eax
       movl $Bash,%ebx
       movl $AddrToBash,%ecx
       movl $NULL2,%edx
       int  $0x80

       #exit routine


     Exit:
       movl $10,%ebx
       movl $1,%eax
       int $0x80
```

The following Output is

```
4000b0: 31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  4000b2:   c7 04 25 f2 00 60 00    movl   $0x6000e0,0x6000f2
  4000b9:   e0 00 60 00 
  4000bd:   b8 0b 00 00 00          mov    $0xb,%eax
  4000c2:   bb e0 00 60 00          mov    $0x6000e0,%ebx
  4000c7:   b9 f2 00 60 00          mov    $0x6000f2,%ecx
  4000cc:   ba f6 00 60 00          mov    $0x6000f6,%edx
  4000d1:   cd 80                   int    $0x80

00000000004000d3 <Exit>:
  4000d3:   bb 0a 00 00 00          mov    $0xa,%ebx
  4000d8:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
  4000dd:   cd 80                   int    $0x80
```

how to remove 00, 
I did the changed like `eax` to `al`, `bx` to bl blahahahahahaha...... but not work
can someone modify it.......

Comment: Please fix the markdown of your posting.

Comment: I will never understand why people find it so difficult to click the magic "format code" button. Or even why people don't *look at the preview* and realize that half their code **is not even being shown because of bad formatting**. If you can't be bothered to look at your **own** question, why do you expect anyone else to read it?

Comment: And what do you mean "without null"? Which null do you want to remove, and *why*?

Comment: Just a wild quess: Do you want to avoid opcodes that contains byte 0? Like for a string oveflow exploit?

Comment: If you remove all the nulls, your code will do something completely different.

Comment: @Anon: technically it's possible, but it requires lots of knowledge and patience. For example, if you manage to write base64 decoder with this property, you can attach any code to it.

Comment: Basically i want to print the host name on FREEBSD doing Buffer overflow. So i need to know how i write the Assembly code in FreeBSD to avoid 00's .....

Comment: you should say avoid - not removing ~ seems you're trying to build a shellcode ;)

Answer (score 6):

You have to take a lot of things into consideration if you want to avoid NULL bytes in shellcode. However, most of the time it involves replacing instructions with equivalent ones.

For example,

```
mov $0, %eax
```

produces `b8 00 00 00 00` which contains NULL bytes. Replacing it with

```
xor %eax, %eax
```

is semantically equivalent but produces `31 c0` instead.

For a good introduction on writing shellcode, read [Smashing The Stack For Fun And Profit](http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html). The book [Hacking: The Art of Exploitation](http://rogunix.com/docs/Reversing&Exploiting/Hacking%20-%20The%20Art%20of%20Exploitation_2nd%20Ed.pdf) contains a section (0x523) about avoiding NULL bytes in shellcode.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to use opcodes that does not contain byte 0. This could be useful only to create buffer overflows with strings (example: `strcpy()`).

Either you learn assembly wery well, so that you would know the binary encoding of most common instructions by heart, thus being able to avoid 0. Or by using existing tools for that: something that encodes the original code to a representation without 0 bytes (example: BCD, base64, or even ASCII string like `010010010`), and prepends to it a special decriptor that does not contain zeros.

Comment: THanks for Reply ......  I need to print hostname using execv system calll in Assembly language. The operating System is FreeBSD. after compiling and running the code i will get produce the opcode.... But the opcode must not contain 00 pair......... but i dont know how to do that